# Hive unique string count

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a column  of stings in a Hive table and I want to count the number of occurrences of each string in this column. How can I do that?

Comment: The two answers below both interpret your question in a different way: My answer assumes you want the number of times *each* string appears, while Kugathasan assumed you wanted to count *how many* unique strings there are. Perhaps you could reword your question to be a little more clear about which of these you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Martin.I am trying to get the number of times each string appears in the columns. Your command below works but when I test it on small data it get incorrect counts. See below for the results.

Comment: So we can be clear about what you're trying and what's happening, could you update your question to show what you tried, what the result was, and what you expected? That will make it easier to give a good answer. It would also help to know a little about the schema of the table you're trying to query.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to group by the column and then count the number of items in each group. Something like this:

```
SELECT somecolumn, count(1) AS count
FROM sometable
GROUP BY somecolumn
```

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried the following command : SELECT res, count(1) AS count   FROM results where field='title' GROUP BY res LIMIT 20;
but I got these results                                    !! Lady Gaga-Bad Romance 2
!!! BEST TECHNO SONG !!! 2
!!! FRAUENARZT - LASS DiCH GEHN (SPREiZ DEiNE BEiNE) LYRiCS !!! 2
!ACPowerOff 2
!alert1 4
!alert2 4
!alert3 4
!alert4 4
!alert5 4
!alert52 2
!alert6 4
!back 4
!bipbip 4
!blackpoint 6
!button 2
!button_off 2
!button_on 2
!checkoff 4
!checkon 4

Comment: How did that response differ from what you expected?

Comment: There are counts of 2 but the strings are not duplicated.

Comment: In order to understand why I'd need to see a representative sample of your dataset. Could you please edit your question to include this, along with some more details about the schema, and another copy of the resultset you pasted here but formatted so we can actually read it?

Answer (score 0):

Query that I think is correct:

```
SELECT columnA,columnB,COUNT(distinct column C)
from table_name
group by columnA,columnB
```

Is this correct? SQL is fine too.